# maximum subarray using Kadane's

Tags: algorithm, arrays

I used Kadane's algorithm to write "find maximum sub-array"(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) like below, but my professor said, "I'm actually not sure what your MSA program does but it certainly does not find the maximum sub-array."
Please tell me what I did wrong.

```
int findMaximumSubarray(int array[], int length){
  int max1=array[0];
  int max2=array[0];
  int i;

  for (i=0; i<length; i++){
    max1 = findMax(array[i],max1+array[i]);
    max2 = findMax(max2,max1);
  }
  return max2;
}

int findMax(int x, int y) {
  if(x>y) return x;
  else return y;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you add the code by adding 4 spaces at the new line. That way we can just copy and paste to analyse your code.

Comment: please modify your question. add more details instead of links

Comment: Hi,
I tried to put my code, but I didn't know how, so I took a picture.

Comment: I just typed it in. You add 4 spaces at the start of the line to add it as code. What language is this? Java?

Answer (score 0):

It's nearly right, but think about what happens to `max1` in the very first loop iteration.  That's right, I'm not gonna just tell you what the bug is.